# c++ create a class exception

Tags: c++, class, exception

I'm having trouble creating a simple class exception.

Basically, I have to throw an exception if my number of score on a golf game is 0, because the method decreases the score by 1.

How would I create a simple exception class in this case?

My current code looks like this, but I'm stuck.

```
// looking for when score[i] = 0 to send error message 
class GolfError : public exception {
  public:
    const char* what() {}
    GolfError() {}
    ~GolfError(void);

  private:
    string message;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually you derive from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) and override [`virtual const char* std::exception::what()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what), like in the minimal example below:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Exception : public std::exception
{
    std::string _msg;
public:
    Exception(const std::string& msg) : _msg(msg){}

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return _msg.c_str();
    }
}; 

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw Exception("Something went wrong...\n");
    }
    catch(Exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Wandbox</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4Yhj2QWyqKe6XQAo)

You then throw this exception in the code that tests for the score. However, you usually throw an exception whenever something "exceptional" happen and the program cannot proceed further, like impossibility of writing into a file. You don't throw an exception when you can easily correct, like e.g. when you validate input.

Comment: This helps! thank you!, yeah my assignment requires i create a class exception for this, i got everything else mostly done and tested, again thank you very much

Comment: @blayrex BTW, if one of the answers here address your question to your satisfaction, you should accept it in the future, so other users of this site see that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 9):

People often inherit from [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) instead of the base `std::exception` type. It already implements what() for you.

```
#include <stdexcept>

class GolfError : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    GolfError(const char* what) : runtime_error(what) {}
};
```

Comment: That's a good point, +1. In OPs case I guess this is the way to go. In case you want more control over the exception, then probably deriving from `std::exception` is more flexible.